# Having issue in jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using GD library to draw image and after that i am going to get that image using jquery ajax. But there is an issue when i update the image the jquery ajax does not get the updated image while when i check the directory the image updates. So please help me in this case how would i get the updated image in jquery ajax response.

My jquery code for getting the response from php file is as below:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "create.php",
    dataType:"text",
    data:myData,
    success:function(response){
        //location.reload();
        var result = response.split("|");

        document.getElementById('img').innerHTML = result[0]; // This is the image

        document.getElementById('download').innerHTML = result[1]; // this is a href link for some other purpose
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

Please help me in this case. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

not sure about caching, try `create.php?123451234(randomNumber)` instead.

can you also add the output of `result` to your answer?

I think the main error is that you set the `innerHTML` which replaces more than you need.

why not use like

```
jQuery.('#img').attr('src', result[0]);
```

**Update:**

Looking at your code, replace this:

```
<div id="img"><img src="images/quotepreivewimg.gif" alt="" /></div>
```

by this:

```
<div><img id="img" src="images/quotepreivewimg.gif" alt="" /></div>
```

then use the above jQuery.attr function to load the picture

Comment: http://www.quotewebster.com/create-own-quote please go to that link and check it yourself

Comment: then this will work imn your case: `jQuery.('#img img').attr('src', result[0])`;`

Comment: @user2226181: i just looked at the code from link, what you posted in your question is correct code. but it was impossible to understand from just your question. your problem is caching, because the image filename stays the same. you have to add a GET parameter to your image filename within PHP to prevent caching. for example `$imgfile = $imgfile.'?'.microtime(true);`

Comment: Thank you so much x4rf41 for helping

Answer (score 1):

This cannot work:

```
document.getElementById('img').innerHTML
```

An image doesn't have any inner html code, you have to use the src property:

```
document.getElementById('img').src = result[0];
```

Comment: So when i use this it will give me the updated image? I think may be date and time also use in somewhere? what do you say?

Comment: if `result[0]` is a correct image file, this will change the displayed image. if you modify the image but keep the same name, you should add a random GET parameter to the image filename to prevent caching. usually with something like this: `.src = result[0]+'?'+(new Date().getTime());`. if you tell me how result[0] looks like i can give u exact code

Comment: result[0] looks like this <img src="imagename" alt />

Comment: Please give me the exact code if you can and .src is not working .innerHTML is working

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
document.getElementById('img').innerHTML = result[0];
```

to:

```
document.getElementById('img').src = result[0];
```

**Updated version:**

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "create.php",
    dataType:"text",
    data:myData,
    success:function(response){
        //location.reload();
        var result = response.split("|");

        document.getElementById('img').src = result[0]; // we need the src property here

        document.getElementById('download').innerHTML = result[1]; // this is a href link for some other purpose
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.